# ob_start(): second array member is not a valid method

Tags: php, web

I installed a web application, but while opening the web application in a browser getting message

```
Warning: ob_start(): second array member is not a valid method in /opt/lampp/htdocs/-/mainfile.php on line 80

Notice: ob_start(): failed to create buffer in /opt/lampp/htdocs/-/mainfile.php on line 80
```

I saw the mainfile.php, the statement throwing this message is :

```
ob_start(array('ob_gzhandler',5));
```

ob_start('ob_gzhandler') is working fine but if array() is used its not working.

Comment: parameter should be a valid callback function

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Yeah, well, that code is nonsense.

Comment: @deceze ... I think code is sensible because, it is the part of <pre>PHPNews</pre> web application. I heard it was working fine for few others too.

Comment: The same PHPNews on SourceForge that was last updated 9 years ago? Just because such a project contains a line of code doesn't mean it makes sense. The `array(..)` syntax for a callback is defined by PHP, and in this case it amounts to calling `ob_gzhandler::5()`, **which obviously doesn't make sense.**

Comment: @deceze ... ya it updated before 3 years, but I need to use the application for testing in my probject... the error mentioned above is arise, while running that PHPNews application.

Comment: Well, the code itself seems to be much older: https://sourceforge.net/p/newsphp/code/HEAD/tree/. But be that as it may, that line doesn't make sense, period. You can deactivate error reporting in your PHP configuration and you won't see the error, unless you want to fix it yourself. That's the most likely explanation how "it worked" for other people too...

Comment: @deceze ... Ok.. Thank you..